# ASP.NET Web API having issues with POST an entity with DateTimeOffset property

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, system.text.json

I'm building an API that receives an entity with a property: `DateTimeOffset? LastAnalysisDate`. The real data that will be getting passed to this API will be in the: "2023-05-31T10:16:08-0400" format which from what I understand should be correct ISO 8601 format. At first I thought I needed use DateTime.ParseExact() but it doesn't even get to that part before throwing the error.

Works:

```
{
  "key": "string",
  "name": "string",
  "lastAnalysisDate": "2023-08-18T10:16:08"
}
```

Doesn't work:

```
{
  "key": "string3",
  "name": "string3",
  "lastAnalysisDate": "2023-05-31T10:16:08-0400"
}
```

Giving this error:

```
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "00-a416afb97a9483f8ce7e6a3980bc81e8-7193a408f021a1e2-00",
  "errors": {
    "project": [
      "The project field is required."
    ],
    "$.lastAnalysisDate": [
      "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Nullable`1[System.DateTimeOffset]. Path: $.lastAnalysisDate | LineNumber: 3 | BytePositionInLine: 48."
    ]
  }
}
```

The POST method from the API Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
public async Task<ActionResult<Project>> CreateProject(Project project)
{
    await _context.Projects.AddAsync(project);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetProject), new { id = project.Id }, project);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> should be correct ISO 8601 format

According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/system-text-json-support#support-for-the-iso-8601-12019-format) uses not just ISO 8601 but:

> The `System.Text.Json` library parses and writes DateTime and DateTimeOffset values according to the ISO 8601-1:2019 extended profile.

Which it seems requires delimiter in the offset part (from [Date and time components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/system-text-json-support#date-and-time-components) section):

> Time offset   "K" Either "Z" or "('+'/'-')HH':'mm".

i.e. the following should work:

```
{
  "key": "string",
  "name": "string",
  "lastAnalysisDate": "2023-08-18T10:16:08-04:00"
}
```

If format can't be changed you can workaround with custom converter:

```
public class DateTimeOffsetParseConverter : JsonConverter<DateTimeOffset>
{
    public override DateTimeOffset Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        Debug.Assert(typeToConvert == typeof(DateTimeOffset));
        return DateTimeOffset.Parse(reader.GetString() ?? string.Empty);
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, DateTimeOffset value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

For example:

```
var dateTimeOffset = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<DateTimeOffset>("\"2023-05-31T10:16:08-0400\"",
    new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        Converters = { new DateTimeOffsetParseConverter() }
    });
```

Comment: The example you said should work (with the -0400) is the correct format I need and from my understanding it should be what the API is looking for out of the box, I don’t understand why it isn’t working. I can change the data going to the API but I didn’t want to add that layer of complexity if I didn’t have to, plus I would like to figure out why it isn’t working from a knowledge standpoint.

Comment: @wjhanna have you checked the linked docs?

Comment: Yes, unless I’m just not understanding it correctly it says that System.Text.Json parses the format that I need out of the box. If there’s some additional logic that I need to do like DateTime.ParseExact I don’t seem to be able to do it in the POST method because the validation error occurs before I can put any extra logic in.

Comment: @wjhanna 1) It explicitly says that the delimiter is required in the offset part, so not the format you need 2) you can configure serializer (i.e. add custom.converter from.the answer) for ASP.NET Core to use, so there is no need to use`Parse` explicitly.